# How to achieve SharePoint Search Results in both List and Tile View?

Tags: sharepoint-server, search-results, enterprise-search, display-template

I am using Search navigation web part and Search Results web part to show the search results. The default search results showing in **List View** and I need the results to be switched in both List view and tile view.

If I click tile Icon in search navigation I need the search results to display in tile view.

[image]

And If I click the List Icon in search navigation I need the Search Results to be displayed in List View.

[image]

The result items can be of any type and the item preview should be displayed when hovering for list view and there is no hover-over preview for tile view and preview will be displayed in image marked preview section(tile view image).
I have analyzed about this and there is almost 12 item and hover panel display templates by search results default and nearly 8 display templates uses commonItem body template. And for the person, video, picture display templates is entirely different. So, If this can be achieved by using 2 display templates(one for list view and other for tile view) then **"Is that possible to integrate all templates logic into single template?"** for both list and tile view and **"What is the way to switch between tile and list view from search navigation icon?"** or please suggest me some idea to achive this.